# XNA Deferred Shader, Replace BasicEffect

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, deferred-rendering

I have implemented deferred shading in my XNA 4.0 project, meaning that I need all objects to start out with the same shader "*RenderGBuffer.fx*". How can I use a custom Content Processor to:

1. Not load any textures by default (I want to manually do this)
2. Use "*RenderGBuffer.fx*" as the default shader instead of BasicEffect

Below is the work so far:

```
public class DeferredModelProcessor : ModelProcessor
{
   EffectMaterialContent deferredShader;

   public DeferredModelProcessor()
   {

   }

   protected override MaterialContent ConvertMaterial(MaterialContent material, ContentProcessorContext context)
   {
       deferredShader = new EffectMaterialContent();
       deferredShader.Effect = new ExternalReference<EffectContent>("DeferredShading/RenderGBuffer.fx");         

       return context.Convert<MaterialContent, MaterialContent>(deferredShader, typeof(MaterialProcessor).Name);
   }
}
```

Comment: please show some code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: I added some code, and thanks for point out the rate.

Comment: I suspect that your question might receive more attention at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com where lots of experts regarding this are...

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll try there. Here's the link for future readers:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43290/xna-deferred-shading-replace-basiceffect